# The method enable(Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>)in the type Network is not applicable for the arguments(Optional<Object>)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to run this below selenium code, but the method "enable" is giving the below mentioned error. please help.

```
Error: The method enable(Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>, Optional<Integer>) in the type Network is not applicable for the arguments (Optional<Object>, Optional<Object>, Optional<Object>)
```

Code:

```
public class TestNetworkRequest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.manage().window().maximize();

           
           DevTools devTools = ((ChromeDriver)driver).getDevTools();
           devTools.createSession();
           
           devTools.send(Network.enable(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty()));
        
           devTools.send(Network.setBlockedURLs(ImmutableList.of("*.jpg",".png","*.jpeg")));
           
           driver.get("http:www.makemytrip.com");
```

I have tried basic code for devTools in selenium , enable method is giving the mentioned error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why cannot assign value to List with 'general wildcard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75332666/why-cannot-assign-value-to-list-with-general-wildcard)

Comment: cause Optional<Integer> not extends Optional<Object>,Integer is a subtype of Object, but Optional<Integer> is not a subtype of Optional<Object>