# Unexpected behaviour of generics wildcard

Tags: java, generics

I'm interested in understanding why, in the example given below, the row instantiating `wrapper2` gives a compilation error:

```
java: incompatible types: inference variable V has incompatible bounds
    equality constraints: java.util.stream.Stream<EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>>
    lower bounds: java.util.stream.Stream<EntityVersion<Product>>
```

Example:

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.val;

@Data
class BaseEntity {
    UUID id;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Product extends BaseEntity {
    String name;
};

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class EntityVersion<T extends BaseEntity> {
    String status;
    T entity;
}

record EntityVersions(Map<String, Stream<EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>>> entityVersions) {}

class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[]args){
        EntityVersion<Product> product = new EntityVersion<>("new", new Product("Product 1"));
                
        Stream<EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>> products1 = Stream.of(product);
        val wrapper1 = new EntityVersions(Map.of("products", products1));
        
        Stream<EntityVersion<Product>> products2 = Stream.of(product);
        val wrapper2 = new EntityVersions(Map.of("products", products2));
    }
}
```

Comment: A `List<String>` is not a `List<Object>` and a `Stream<EntityVersion<Product>>` is not a `Stream<EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>>`. But there’s no sense in storing a Stream anyway.

Comment: Even though `EntityVersion<Product>` is a subtype of `EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>`, that does not mean `Stream<EntityVersion<Product>>` is a subtype of `Stream<EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>>`, in the same way that `Stream<Dog>` is not a subtype of `Stream<Animal>`. See also [this recent question I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75332666/5133585), which is also about the subtyping of nested generics. They follow the same rules as a single layer of generics, really.

Comment: Rather, `Stream<EntityVersion<Product>>` is a subtype of `Stream<? extends EntityVersion<? extends BaseEntity>>`.